# How do I (sum) the output of a list?

Tags: sum

List

```
L= [23, 91, 0, -11, 4, 23, 49]
```

Code

```
 for i in L:
        if i > 10:
            num = i * 30
        else:
            num = i * 1
        if num % 2 == 0:
              num += 6
              if i > 50: 
                num -= 10
                if i != -11:
                   num += 10 
        print(num)
```

Output

```
696
2736
6
-11
10
696
1476
```

I'm trying to sum the numbers in the output and then divide the total by 2.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a variable `sum` outside the loop then, add the value of `num` to `sum` before the `print` statement. Finally, `print(sum/2)` once outside the loop.

```
sum = 0
for i in L:
   
  ...
  sum += num
  print(num)

print(sum/2)
```